# Why do I get this Error? SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, xml, pyxb

I'm trying to validate some XML-Files using python, but I am already getting an error when I try to convert the schema to a py-file.

My two lines of code so far:

```
import pyxb

pyxbgen -u /Users/xyz/XML_Validation/schemas/schema_short.xsd -m schema_short
```

The Error i get is "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", highlighting "schema_short" at the end.

Why do I get this Error? I've compared my code to examples online, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Python/IDLE Version 2.7.6
Pyxb Version 1.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing syntax. `pyxbgen -u /Users/xyz/XML_Validation/schemas/schema_short.xsd -m schema_short` is not valid python, it looks like a command line call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run that second line in IDLE--it has invalid Python syntax.

It should be run through the command line:

```
$ pyxbgen -u /Users/xyz/XML_Validation/schemas/schema_short.xsd -m schema_short
```

[IDLE](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html) is a Python IDE.  Meaning, it only accepts valid Python code.